# Register a COM object using InstallShield

Tags: com, windows-installer, installshield

I am using InstallShield 2011. I have a COM object that needs registered during installation. I cant seem to find anywhere where it instructs you on how to do this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a component and add your COM dll/ocx to it and right click it to mark it as key file if needed.    Then right click the file and select "Extract COM".  You should see a bunch of progress messages as it harvests the various registry entries.   Build your installer and test it on a clean machine.

Comment: What is an ocx? Also, when I right click on it, as in the picture above, it seems as if Extract COM is disabled.

Comment: Object Linking and Embedding (OLE) Control Extension (OCX).  It's a COM ( ActiveX) server dll.  ( Google it )

Comment: You can also set the "COM Extract at Build" property on the component.  Build it and see if it works or if it gives you an error.  BTW, have you used regsvr32 or Depends to verify that it actually is a COM dll?

Comment: Can you do this with the Limited Edition of InstallShield?

Comment: I am not getting how and where to create component! Can you please elaborate?

Comment: https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/helplibrary/IHelpCompCreation.htm

Answer (score 2):

Please see Rod Maupin's blog《COM Extraction/Registration in an InstallShield Project》 http://www.installationdeveloper.com/3028/com-extractionregistration-in-an-installshield-project/

Answer (score 0):

There is a manual method of registering COM described <del>[here](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=installshield16helplibsp1-IHelpAdvComRegistrationhtm&sliceId=&docTypeID=DT_MACROVISIONHELPNET_1_1&dialogID=135263635&stateId=0%200%20135257690)</del>. It also shows a method, which is **not** recommended, to register automatically during build.

(Google for *"Configuring COM Registration Settings Manually"* if the link stops working).

**EDIT**:

- The link has indeed stopped working - it seems Installshield's knowledge base is now login only. What a shame.
- Adding a link to Flexera's (Installshield owner) helpnet home page: **http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/**. Click on the "Help Libraries" links in the left column for online help (nice looking stuff that looks like it is made with [RoboHelp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_RoboHelp)).
- Might as well add a direct link to a similar topic: [**Configuring COM Registration Settings Manually**](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/IHelpAdvComRegistration.htm#OrganizingFiles_2400211645_1151530).