# Outlook folder custom UI

Tags: c#, wpf, installation, activex, outlook-addin

I am building an Outlook 2010 addin (VS 2010, c#, .net framework 4) that follows the steps from this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/e2eblog/archive/2008/01/09/outlook-folder-homepage-hosting-wpf-activex-and-windows-forms-controls.aspx

Everything is running under VS but can't build a working installer. Tried also with the sample code - I have created the installer but the addin does not load the custom UI when running outside Visual Studio (the addin IS loaded, just the custom UI is not loaded).

Also, tried to deploy it using InstallShield LE (with the UI code in the same project or in another project - a user control library).

As a last resort, extracted the registry keys for the user control and tried to apply them as presented here: [Register a COM object using InstallShield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665068/register-a-com-object-using-installshield)

Thoughts? What else should I try?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you did all the steps described in the [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx) article.

Do you get any UI errors? See [How to: Show Add-in User Interface Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx).

Comment: Yes, the process of building the installer is OK (have built dozens of Office addins before) and no, there are no UI errors.
I think the issue here is the browser security that does not load the custom UI (user control) because it does not properly register on the client. From the debugger, it's VS that handles registration but none of the installers are doing it properly. Yes, I have marked the usercontrol DLL for COM registration on both Install Shield and Setup project...

Comment: > the addin does not load the custom UI - are you talking about the custom Ribbon UI for the add-in? Do you see Ribbon controls?

Comment: Actually no. If you take a look at the sample plugin in my initial question, you'll see that it loads a custom UI for a specific outlook folder (like a custom view for that folder) by creating a local HTML file used as a host for the custom UI. In that HTML file it loads (javascript) a usercontrol created in WPF <- THAT is the custom UI I am referring to.
Thank you for you time...