# Dll not appearing in references for VBA after installing using install shield

Tags: vba, excel, installshield

I created an install shield project for an Excel add-in.

I selected `.dll` file and the `.tlb` file to be moved to the `GAC` (in destination folder) and program files folder

[image]

Those files are present in the program files folder

But when I go to Excel, click on tools-> reference, they are not appearing in that list!

I had to manually browse to the location of that `.tlb` file and select it

What change should i make so that it automatically comes in the references list

Comment: Did you register the .dll and .tlb in the installer?

Comment: No I have only selected and added the .dll and .tlb files
how to register them?

Comment: Does your installer run `RegAsm` for the dll?

Comment: @dePatinkin No can we make it register the dll and tlb files after installing?

Comment: [Register a COM object using InstallShield](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665068/register-a-com-object-using-installshield) might be relevant.  Basically regasm and regsvr32, but I haven't used Installshield in years.

Answer (score 1):

This article gives you description of two methods to do the registration with Installshield: [Installshield Register.Net DLLs](http://www.iwasdot.com/installshield-execute-a-batch-script/).

I definitely recommend **Approach 2 - Run a .bat file to register the files**. This approach runs the RegAsm for the install and uninstall processes using a batch file. This will give you control over the registration process, where you know exactly what is done, and you can handle all bitness scenarios 32/64/Wow64. In Approach 1 you don't, as stated in the article:

> For some reason, perhaps that I am installing a 32bit component on a 64bit machine, this didn’t work as expected. [...] some DLL’s perform post registration actions the run when you run RegAsm.exe VirtualCam.dll /nologo /codebase but don’t get captured when you run RegAsm.exe VirtualCam.dll /nologo /codebase /regfile

If possible I would recommend switching to a different installation package creator, that supports run operations and gives better control over the process than using a batch.

*As it's not a native COM dll but a dotNet dll exposed to COM, there's no need for regsvr32 registration.

Comment: I am still facing some issues in the installer  :( 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123731/what-are-the-files-to-be-included-in-installshield-for-excel-add-in-com-object?noredirect=1#comment48359552_30123731